# How to parse string from one column into delimited values in SQL

Tags: sql, string, parsing, amazon-redshift

This is my column in Redshift

```
SHIPMENT_ID
-----------------------------------------
FBA15KS66741, FBA15KS6673D
FBA15NHV7PXX (Oct 20th)
FBA15XNW0SWY 27 balance 2 of 2
FBA15M575MDL &  FBA15M59W1Y5
FBA15NHV7PXX (Oct 20th)
FBA15D7WPZVR /FBA15D7WWTPK/FBA15D7WW1GL
```

I would like to make it

```
SHIPMENT_ID
-----------------------------------------
FBA15KS66741, FBA15KS6673D
FBA15NHV7PXX
FBA15XNW0SWY
FBA15M575MDL, FBA15M59W1Y5
FBA15NHV7PXX
FBA15D7WPZVR, FBA15D7WWTPK, FBA15D7WW1GL
```

In SQL only, what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This works in PostgreSQL, so may work in Redshift depending on feature availability in PG8.

```
WITH items AS
(
  SELECT shipment_id,
         ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_MATCHES(shipment_id,'FBA15[0-9a-zA-z]{7}','g'),'') AS unique_shipment_ids
  FROM dat
)
SELECT shipment_id,
       STRING_AGG(unique_shipment_ids,',') AS shipment_id_csv
FROM items
GROUP BY shipment_id;
```

[image]

I've assumed:

- Each item begins with the characters 'FBA15'
- There are exactly 7 characters after the first 5

You can edit the regexp pattern if my assumptions are incorrect.

The approach is:

1. Use `REGEXP_MATCHES` to capture each item within each row. This creates multiple rows per unique value in shipment_id
2. Use `ARRAY_TO_STRING` to convert those values to `text`, rather than `text[]`
3. Use `STRING_AGG` to join them back together with a comma separator

I found that I could not use `STRING_AGG` directly around `REGEXP_MATCHES` as I get the error `aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls`, so opted for a CTE. I assume a subquery would work as well.